# Is there an easy way to bulk swap the file names of two files in Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

Is there an easy way to bulk swap the file names of two files in Windows?

I have `File_A.txt` and `File_B.txt` and after the operation, `File_A.txt` is now called `File_B.txt`, and vice versa.

```bat
::  Old Name         New Name       
    File_A.txt  -->  File_B.txt
    File_B.txt  -->  File_A.txt
```

This article has some solutions, but I want to do it in bulk, like randomly swap a bunch of filenames in a folder:

[Easily swap file names?](https://superuser.com/questions/359812/easily-swap-file-names?newreg=a17ddb144cdd4ecb8012e145dd866fcd)

This Sctipt.Bat also does it, but I've never been able to make it work:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd %~dp0CopyOfFiles

:: generating a 'random number' that I wont use because this program is annoying 
set m=%random%

set loop=0
:loop
set /a loop=%loop%+1 
if "%loop%"=="1000" goto nexter

::calculating 2 random boi
set n=0
for %%f in (*.*) do (
   set /A n+=1
   set "file[!n!]=%%f"
)
::Generating an actual random number
set /A "rand1=(n*%random%)/32768+1"
set /A "rand2=(n*%random%)/32768+1"

if "%rand1%" == "%rand2%" goto next
echo %rand1%
echo %rand2%
::chose file from the first folder
move %~dp0CopyOfFiles\!file[%rand1%]! %~dp0CopyOfFiles\ThInGy
move %~dp0CopyOfFiles\!file[%rand2%]! %~dp0CopyOfFiles\!file[%rand1%]!
move %~dp0CopyOfFiles\ThInGy %~dp0CopyOfFiles\!file[%rand2%]!
:next

goto loop

:nexter
```

Any help would be appreciated!
This is DIFFERENT from other similar questions because I do not want to manually rename the files “file-a.txt” and I do not want to use only text files, it could be .png files or .brstms

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Batch rename part of a file in windows](https://superuser.com/questions/15944/batch-rename-part-of-a-file-in-windows)

Comment: No it doesn’t, I edited the post to explain it more.

Comment: So, rename `File_A.anyExtension` to `File_B.anyExtension`?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I want, but the file name can also be anything, not just File_A and File_B

Answer (score 0):

```bat
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d "%~dp0CopyOfFiles"

for %%i in (.\*.*
    )do ren "%%~fi" "%%~ni_tmp%%~xi"
    
for %%i in (.\*_tmp.*)do if defined _old (
     set "_new=%%~nxi" && ren "%%~dpi!_old!" "!_new:_tmp=!"
     ren "%%~dpi!_new!" "!_old:_tmp=!" && set "_old=")else set "_old=%%~nxi"

endlocal
```

---

- Or in a more conventional code layout:

```bat
@echo off 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d "%~dp0CopyOfFiles"

for %%i in (*) do ren "%%~fi" "%%~ni_tmp%%~xi"

for %%i in (*_tmp.*) do if defined _old (
      set "_new=%%~nxi"
      ren "%%~dpi!_old!" "!_new:_tmp=!"
      ren "%%~dpi!_new!" "!_old:_tmp=!"
      set "_old="
    ) else (
      set "_old=%%~nxi"
    )

endlocal
```

---

It is possible to do it for two or more (always in pairs), but keep in mind that you don't have a direct operation to change the name between files, use loops.

**1.** Rename all your files one time in order to preserve the original name

```bat
:: Example ::
ren File_A.txt File_A_tmp.txt
```

**2.** Rename the files a second time and use the preserved names restoring the original name in the destination file

```bat
:: Example ::
ren File_A_tmp.txt File_B.txt
```

---

---

## Some further reading:

- **[`Set /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**
- **[`For ?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**
- **[`For /F ?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**
- **[`Ren | Rename /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)**
- **[`If condition() else condition()`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**
- **[Redirection: - `| >nul 2>nul 2>&1 <nul < > 2> 1>`](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**
- **[DelayedExpansion (Refer: `!Expand_RunTime_Variable!`)](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)**
- **[An A-Z Index of Windows CMD commands on ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)**